# Open a file audio in R.Raw

Tags: android, audio

I have to open a file that in the `/res/raw/` folder, but it seems that android, doesn't recognize the path.

Here is my code:

```
public static void openRec()
{
    //this is the wav file that I have to analyze
    File file = new File("/res/raw/chirp.wav");

    try {
       FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
       chirp = new byte[(int) file.length()];
       in.read(chirp);


        Log.d("xxx", "" + chirp.length);
        in.close();


    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

EDIT:
I have another method openRec in which, the path is passed as argument:

```
public static void openRec(String path) {

       File file = new File(path);
       try {
           FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
           recording = new byte[(int) file.length()];
           in.read(recording);
           Log.d("xxx", "" + recording.length);
           in.close();
       } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       } catch (IOException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
```

}

I would a method that do the same thing but with the ffile in /res/raw. How do I that?

Comment: Resources are not files in the filesystem of the device. They are entries in a ZIP archive that is the APK file.

Answer (score 2):

Use in this manner

```
public static void openRec()
{
    //this is the wav file that I have to analyze


    try {
       InputStream in = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.chirp);
       chirp = new byte[(int) file.length()];
       in.read(chirp);


        Log.d("xxx", "" + chirp.length);
        in.close();


    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: thx for the answer. Now the program doesn't throw any exception but the length returned is always zero. Why?

Comment: Use int length = inputStream.available();
 To get length. Accept my answer if it is correct